# Issues when posting data through Jquery Ajax with IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, content-type

We have a JavaScript client which POST data using [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). The client post some content through the message body which server receives and processes. When I am sending data through IE 11, Chrome or FireFox, server is able to receive content posted in the message body.

But when I emulate IE 8 by changing `Document Mode` to `8` and `User Agent String` to `IE 8` in IE developer toolbar (as shown in below image), server is not receiving content sent through message body. I am facing same issue when site is run using IE 8.

[image: IE 8 emulation using IE developer toolbar]

Belwo code snippet shows how I am posting the data through [JQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/). DataTables post the data (sort param, sort order, no of records to fetch etc) in the message body automatically, that is why we don't see any additional property in Ajax obejct.

```
 ajax: {
    url: baseURL + '/data',
    type: 'POST'
  },
```

After lot of investigation, I found there is a **difference in the request header** which is preventing data from being posted on the server. When the request is sent through IE 8 mode, `content type` is not mentioned in the request header. I tried adding `content type` property in ajax object but event that is not helping. Please provide your suggestions.

[image]

```
ajax: {
   url: baseURL + '/data',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
  },
```

I verified my understanding by posting data with a REST client. When `content type` is mentioned in header, server gets the data. But when `content type` is missing server does not get data posted through body.

[image]

Comment: Make sure there are no duplicate ID's or console.logs

Comment: @SwaghettiYolonese: Thank you for reply. What do you mean by duplicate Id?

Comment: That there are no more than 1 elements with the same id attribute.

Comment: @SwaghettiYolonese: All the elements have unique id.

Comment: Then I have no idea what it can be..